# openlayer 4.4 getArea() gives a bad result

Tags: openlayers

`getArea()` gives 206.85693359375 m2 for a square of 10 meters on the side. The coordinates of this geometry are:

```
A: (10) […]
​​0: 349342.54170016386
​​1: 5765285.69787908
​​2: 349356.90080337634
​​3: 5765285.67265447
​​4: 349356.87564911734
​​5: 5765271.266706267
​​6: 349342.51656936127
​​7: 5765271.291930803
​​8: 349342.54170016386
​​9: 5765285.69787908
​​length: 10
```

What's wrong with `feature.getGeometry().getArea()`?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct in projection units, and is close to this approximate calculation

```
 349356.90 -  349342.54 = 14.36
5765285.69 - 5765271.26 = 14.43

 14.36 * 14.43 = 207.21
```

As you move away from away from the equator in a web mercator projection things look larger so you should use 
`ol.Sphere.getArea(geometry)` to get the true area on the curved surface of the world

Comment: I thought that getArea gave the flat and Cartesian surface of my square of 10 m of side, that is to say 100 m2.
How to get these cartesian area of any polygon with openlayers?

Comment: and Math.abs(wgs84Sphere.geodesicArea(coordinates)) gives 100.1585129900082
how can I get round 100 like Qgis gives ?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that getArea() works well for cartesian projections, like EPSG:2154 for me (and utm ?).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a projection to it, for example:

```
const opts: SphereMetricOptions = { projection: 'EPSG:32634' }
const area = getArea(polygon, opts)
```

See [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#~SphereMetricOptions](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#%7ESphereMetricOptions)